# Problem with loading OpenCV library on Linux server: file too short

Tags: java, opencv, ibm-cloud

I'm having problems loading an OpenCV library on a Linux server. I'm trying to deploy an application with Java components to this environment. I first installed OpenCV using Ubuntu on Windows, then copied the OpenCV .so files into a folder of the Java classpath so they can be found. The structure of the .so files look like this:

[structure of .so files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym8Dq.png)

If I then try to load the library using `System.loadLibrary(NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`, it gives the following error:

```
CRITICAL - M2EE: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/home/vcap/app/data/tmp/project-userlib___415031196935836591/libopencv_java342.so:  
/home/vcap/app/model/resources/libopencv_ml.so.3.4: file too short
```

I think this has something to do with copying the linked .so files to Windows and then deploy them back to Linux, so the link of the libraries is somehow lost, but I have no idea how to do this the proper way.

Hope anyone can help me.

Regards,

Ward

Comment: I don't see why you are coping from windows when you can install OpenCV directly on Linux server. Have you tried installing OpenCV on Linux Server ??

Comment: It's a simple installation process, steps are given in this link https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Comment: It's an IBM Bluemix server, and we push the application to it, with the .so libraries included. I don't know if there is a way to directly install the OpenCV library on the server.

Comment: `Make sure the file(soft link) is not broken!`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you won't be able to *install* dependencies/libraries over *IBM Bluemix server*, unfortunately.

However, you can use ***Java Runtimes*** available on ***IBM Bluemix*** **server** to create a development *envorinment* and then *install* ***OpenCV*** or any other *dependencies/libraries*.

This way, you can use it in your application as well.

Note:
If you need any help in doing so, you can ask me or you can contact the *IBM Bluemix support* team, they will be happy to assist and guide you in this regard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is this the right tutorial to do this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1602_woolf-trs/1602_woolf3-pdf.pdf? If not, could you help me find one?

Comment: Yeah, it seem so. Have you tried contacting IBM Bluemix support ??